# How can I add a soft transition effect to my Blazor server app Navigation menu? (When clicking on main menue item, submenues are listed smoothly)

Tags: blazor-server-side, accordion

In my Blazor server app I have a navigation menue group like below . If I click to the main menue item "CNC", the submenues get visible and listed under the "CNC" menue item.(Like accordion menue). I want to add a soft transition effect to my menue group so that the submenues are visible not immediatly, but with a soft transition effect.

Can I do that with css?

```
<NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="()=>expandSubNav2 = !expandSubNav2">
  <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> CNC
</NavLink>

@if (expandSubNav2)
{
 <NavLink class="" href="CNC_Status">
   <span class="sub_menu">Status</span>
 </NavLink>
 <br>
 <NavLink class="" href="CNC_Files_840D">
   <span class="sub_menu">CNC Files</span>
 </NavLink>
 <br>
 <NavLink class="" href="CNC_MD_840D">
   <span class="sub_menu">CNC MD</span>
 </NavLink>
 <br>
 <NavLink class="" href="NC_Var">
   <span class="sub_menu">NC Variables</span>
 </NavLink>
}
```